# Arithmetic sequence: determine number of addends

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that the sum of first 5 terms of an arithmetic sequence is 65, the sum of the last five terms is 1090,and the sum of all the terms is 5313.Find the number of terms in the sequence

I try to solve this by using the formula 
Sn=n/2(2a+(n-1)d) 
But I don't know how to relate it with the last five terms is 1090..

Comment: How many last terms?

Comment: Shimin: Could you please give a more accurate title and elaborate your question a bit more? Show your own effort to solve this question first and then one can help you from this point on. Here is a guide on how to ask homework-related questions in an acceptable manner: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: Sorry for the unacceptable manner~ I am a newbie and I shall try to improve myself on what you said :) thanks for the advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  The sum of the first five terms being $65$ shows that $5a+10d=65$  If there are $n$ terms, the sum of all the terms is $na+\frac 12n(n-1)d=5313$ Can you write a similar equation for the sum of the last five terms assuming there are $n$ in total?  That will give three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: So means that the equation I added could be Sn-Sn-5=1090..am I right?

Comment: That is correct, if I am reading your notation correctly.

Comment: I got it thank you so much :)